# Logging with Prisma 2 and NestJS - Dependency Injection problem?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma, prisma2

Currently on my first NestJS project. I am using Prisma 2, and would like to log the queries to the console in debug mode, to learn and inspect and avoid n+1 etc!

I have created the `prisma.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy } from '@nestjs/common'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    async onModuleInit() {
        await this.$connect()
    }

    async onModuleDestroy() {
        await this.$disconnect()
    }
}
```

Works fine, I can use it across the API and access the DB. However, according to the Prisma 2 Docs on [Logging](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/logging#event-based-logging), I need to pass

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: [
    { level: 'warn', emit: 'event' },
    { level: 'info', emit: 'event' },
    { level: 'error', emit: 'event' },
  ],
```

and then use it like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    constructor(private prismaService: PrismaService) {
        this.prismaService.$on('query', e => {
            console.log("Query: " + e.query)
            console.log("Duration: " + e.duration + "ms")
        })
    }
```

Sadly, when compiling, I get these errors:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/test.service.ts:9:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type '"query"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"beforeExit"'.

9        this.prismaService.$on('query', e => {
                                ~~~~~~~
src/test.service.ts:10:39 - error TS2339: Property 'query' does not exist on type '() => Promise<void>'.

10             console.log("Query: " + e.query)
                                         ~~~~~
src/test.service.ts:11:42 - error TS2339: Property 'duration' does not exist on type '() => Promise<void>'.

11             console.log("Duration: " + e.duration + "ms")
```

I tried passing the `log` array into the `super()` in the service, without any luck.

Am I just missing something small?

Answer (score 17):

Hey bro I'd been using prima 2 + nestjs, I put the configuration prima in super of parent like this. It has worked wonders for me.

I hope it helps you ;)

This is my prismaService.ts

`prisma.service.ts`

```
import { INestApplication, Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
      constructor() {
        super({
          log: [
            { emit: 'event', level: 'query' },
            { emit: 'stdout', level: 'info' },
            { emit: 'stdout', level: 'warn' },
            { emit: 'stdout', level: 'error' },
          ],
          errorFormat: 'colorless',
        });
      }
      async onModuleInit() {
        await this.$connect();
      }
    
      async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
        this.$on('beforeExit', async (event) => {
          console.log(event.name);
          await app.close();
        });
      }
    }
```

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  constructor(private prismaService: PrismaService) {
    prismaService.$on<any>('query', (event: Prisma.QueryEvent) => {
      console.log('Query: ' + event.query);
      console.log('Duration: ' + event.duration + 'ms');
    });
  }
}
```

Ps: I had to delete the dist folder and run again.

Answer (score 5):

I used this solution founded on the Prisma GitHub issues.

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  constructor(
    private prismaService: PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, 'query'>,
  ) {
    this.prismaService.$on('query', (e) => {
      console.log('Query: ' + e.query);
      console.log('Duration: ' + e.duration + 'ms');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the events you want in the `PrismaClient` generic.

```js
@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, 'query' | 'error'> implements OnModuleInit {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(PrismaService.name);

  constructor() {
    super({
      log: [
        {
          emit: 'event',
          level: 'query',
        },
        {
          emit: 'event',
          level: 'error',
        },
        {
          emit: 'stdout',
          level: 'info',
        },
        {
          emit: 'stdout',
          level: 'warn',
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    this.$on('error', (event) => {
      this.logger.verbose(event.target);
    });
    await this.$connect();
  }

  async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
      await app.close();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an issue with the Prisma Client types. I'd recommend that you open an issue on the Prisma Github repo. Until then you'll need to ignore the provided types by casting to `any` or `unknown`

Answer (score 0):

For the people who are still wondering how this can possibly work, I was able to get some logs using the solution below:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService
  extends PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, 'query' | 'info' | 'warn' | 'error'>
  implements OnModuleInit
{
  constructor() {
    super({
      log: [
        {
          emit: 'event',
          level: 'query',
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    this.$on('query', (event: Prisma.QueryEvent) => {
      console.log('Query: ' + event.query);
      console.log('Duration: ' + event.duration + 'ms');
    });

    await this.$connect();
  }
}
```

If you display the PrismaClient generic class you'll see you can define multiple parameters to it.

This is "documented" here: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/11986#issuecomment-1119739964