Update Prisma Client use middleware with Prisma Extension
Using NestJS with Prisma (Postgres)
this.$use function is indicated as deprecated, how to replace the following code with Prisma Extension ?
PrismaService.ts :
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {
  constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache) {
    super();
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();

    this.$use(async (params, next) => {
      if (params.model === 'User' && params.action === 'update') {
        // Delete cache user info
        const key = `user:${params.args.where.id}`;
        await this.cacheManager.del(key);
      }

      return next(params);
    });
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.$disconnect();
  }
}

Deprecated :


What you are looking for is $extends. You can hook into the query and only modify the model and operation you want:
const extendedPrismaClient = new PrismaClient().$extends(
  query: {
    // only modify `User` model
    user: {
      // only modify 'update' operation
      // destructure parameter and take what you need
      async update({ model, operation, args, query }) {
        // Delete cache user info
        const key = `user:${args.where.id}`;
        await this.cacheManager.del(key);

        return query(args);
      },
    },
  },
)

// Or however you wish to expose your extended client:
this.prisma = extendedPrismaClient;

Source: documentation
A good example on how to implement soft delete: Prisma repo discussions

just tested but the function is never called, I have replace it in the onModuleInit, any idea ?

I see. When you call $extends, a new instance of PrismaClient is returned; any existing instances are not modified. I updated my answer to reflect this.

thanks for your feedback, but how do you integrate it in my PrismaService class ?

It's really hard to say without seeing more of your codebase. I'm not very familiar with NestJs or dependency injection pattern, but probably somewhere you instantiate your PrismaClient; ie. where do you have const something = new PrismaClient(). Replace that with the code I provided.

I looked into dependency injection a bit more. Perhaps this is of use to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68356229/3305924
