listen to any create/update/delete event on Prisma client and take action
I am looking for a way to be aware of any create/update/delete when called from Prisma client with all of args passed:
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }
}


import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service';
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaEventListener implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private readonly prismaService: PrismaService) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    // Listen to the beforeCreate event
    this.prismaService.$on('beforeCreate', async (args) => {
      console.log('beforeCreate args:', args);
      // Your logic here...
    });

    // Add listeners for other events as needed
  }
}

I tried the above PrismaEventListener to listen to beforeCreate event for instance and do sth. But it seems that $on doesnt work the way I expect:
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

I just answered an almost identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78421732/update-prisma-client-use-middleware-with-prisma-extension/78423357
